# Run socket.io client code on nodejs

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am developing a chat application using the nodejs/socket.io on the server side

Now, it is time to test how scalable it is

so, i think i can simulate a large number of soket.io clients effectively using nodejs also , but running the client code this time

the question is, How can i run the socket.io client library on nodejs? is this possible?
if so, can anyone please provide a simple example

my code is running fine on the browser, with the usual development load, the issue is not about the code is running or not, actually i am not planning to run the same client code, just openning a large number of connections , and sending thousands of messages to have a preliminary figure about scalability and resource consumption

also, any suggestion on testing socket.io server scalability will be appreciated

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for isn't going to really be helpful. Even if you could simulate client-side `socket.io` in a `node` process, it wouldn't have the same dynamic properties as actual access from browsers. You'd be able to determine things like the maximum number of connections you could handle without running out of resources, but your general performance metrics would be pretty artificial and not generalizable.

Comment: my code is running fine on the browser, with the usual development load, the issue is not about the code is running or not, actually i am not planning to run the same client code, just openning a large number of connections , and sending thousands of messages to have a preliminary figure about scalability and resource consumption